# Java Regex Replacing double new lines with single new line

Tags: java, regex, string

My code is:

```
String str = str.replaceAll("\\n\\n","\\n");
```

What I am trying to do is replace two consecutive new lines with 1 new line. My code is not doing that.

EDIT AFTER PEOPLE CLOSED THE QUESTION:

I am running the code on windows.

What I wanted to do was replace :  `"This is the first line.\nThis is the second one\nThis is the third one\n\n\This is the fourth one"`

With :    `"This is the first line.\nThis is the second one\nThis is the third one\nThis is the fourth one"`

There you see that after the third line I want 1 newline instead of two.

Comment: Is it correct? When I place this in a jTextArea it still has double new lines....

Comment: @Jens he has no `dot` in his regex..

Comment: If what you're trying to do is replace double newlines with single newlines, no. Your code replaces "slash n slash n" with "slash n" (with actual slashes, not the word "slash")

Comment: You don't need regex for this, it's a simple search + replace. Just use `string.replace("\n\n", "\n")`

Comment: @immibis In java regex which represent line separator can be written as `"\n"` or `"\\n"`. `"\\"` string will will be translated to ``\`` in regex engine producing `\n` metacharacter (it is same rule why we need to write `\d` as `"\\d"` in Java). To represent ``\`` literal followed by `n` OP would have to write it as `"\\\\n"`. But you are kind of right about replacement part. `"\\n"` in replacement will not represent line separator but `n` character (without backslash before it). OP in this case should use simple `"\n"`.

Comment: @SCBose Are you running your code on Windows? If so then lines are not separated with `\n` but with `\r\n`. Can you update your question with more informations like do you want to change only empty lines? You need to remember that line separators are at the end of also non empty lines like `"abc\n\ndef"` will print only one empty line but if you replace those `\n\n` with `\n` you will see two lines with no empty lines between `abc` and `def`. To clarify this post example of simple text you would like to change and expected result (changed text).

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks that was it!! I didn't realise there were two characters for every new line: \r\n..Then what I did was replace all sequences of \r\n with just \n. On the screen both these outputs are the same! But my code was such that it didn't expect that extra \r.. I somehow got it to work but I still don't understand how \r\n render on the screen? Why is it the same as \n? What is the use of two chracters if they do the same thing as \n? You were very helpful.. If you leave your comment as an answer below I'll accept it!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Maybe [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) will explain better what exactly is `\r` and `\n`. Anyway we can't post answer to questions put on hold or closed. Before people will vote to reopen it you would have to improve its quality by adding important details like OS you are running your code and example of input and expected output preferably with explanation why such output should be expected. Input should be basic and simple but contain few different cases like one, two, three, four and five empty lines to show exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Anyway you shouldn't replace `\r\n` with `\n`, even if it works on Windows you should use OS specific separator so if you are sure your code is meant to Windows only replace it with `\r\n`, if you are not sure then you need to use `System.lineSeparator()` method do get OS specific set of characters which represents line separator like for Windows it will return `\r\n` but for Unix it will be only `\n` and maybe for some other OS it will be only `\r` or any other character we don't know yet.

Answer (score 6):

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\n+","\n")); \\ replace one or more newline characters with just one newline..
```

Example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abc\n\nabc";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("hello");
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\n+", "\n"));
}

O/P:
abc

abc
hello
abc
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = str.replaceAll("\n\n","\n");
```

try this